# find available fonts in OSX using default shell or AppleScript

Tags: macos, command-line, shell, fonts, javascript

I'm trying to write a script for Adobe After Effects using extendscript (a proprietary ECMAScript dialect, but mostly ≈ javascript). I can use an inbuilt command `system.callSystem()` to execute a command using the default(?) shell for windows and mac, I'm good with the Windows side of things, but I can't find a bash one liner, or an AppleScript command I can use to list the available fonts.

Is there a way of getting all the fonts on the command line in OSX? Either with a shell script or Applescript which I can call from the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've done this with AE .jsx; try this for your system call:

```
    system_profiler SPFontsDataType | grep -E 'Location'
```

Its very slow, potentially a 10+ second wait with *no* progress indication during the call. I'd love to find a faster way!